# How do I setup nginx and uwsgi when using virtualenv?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, virtualenv

I am going to start using virtualenv for the first time. If I am going to have multiple environments with a django project in each, do I have 1 nginx instance running and have each domain point to the socket of a uwsgi instance running with a -H env parameter? Such that I would have 1 nginx instance running and multiple (1 for each environment) uwsgi instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 1 nginx instance and multiple (1 for each environment) uwsgi instances running.
If you want separate virtualenv's for each project, of course.